# Show summary based on the selected values Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a page where user selects the schedule Type (i.e Custom, Weekly, Monthly, Yearly)

and based on the selection each schedule Type has a form associated with it, what I want is that If all the values are filled I want to run a function inside the controller which will perform the logic and returns an array or sets an array within the controller.

I want to then update the view accordingly like if the array has data it will repeat the records.

let say I've this piece of code

```
weeklySchedule: {
    repeatOn: [{id:2,label:"Tuesday"},{id:1,label:"Monday"}],
    repeatEvery: [{id: 1, label: "1"}],
    startDate: '',
    endDate: ''
}
```

these all values are attached to view, start and end date value comes from a date picker.

What I want is to perform some function xyz which will calculate something and return data or sets the data inside a controller.

This will be binded to the view so if the dates are changed the summary gets updated accordingly.

Angular 1.6

Thanks

Comment: This is a question/answer site. What is your specific problem and question? Please take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl I know this very well that this is question/answer site, can you please read the question again you will find out what trouble I was having.

anyways I've solved this problem and the solution was
$scope.$watch('value', function(){}, true);

Thanks for your concern though!